# CX_oracle update query is not working in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cx-oracle

```
            try:
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    cursor.execute('update m_password set password = :new_password , updater_id = :updater_id_dic , update_date = :update_date_dic where user_cd = :user_cd_dic and  del_flg = :del_flag_dic', queryDictionary)
                    # Commit
                    connection.commit()

                    # Close the cursor
                    cursor.close()

                    # Close the database connection
                    connection.close()
                    return {
                        'status': "success",
                        'errorCode': 0,
                        'errorMessage': json.dumps("")
                    }
            except: cx_Oracle.IntegrityError as e:
                    errorObj, = e.args
                    return {
                        'status': "error",
                        'errorCode': errorObj.code,
                        'errorMessage': json.dumps(errorObj.message)
```

I am trying to update the value of oracle database . Database connection is alright . I can get the value from database . But update the value is not working . It shows success but value is not actually updated . Also there is no error .

also lambda log showing successfully executed . Please check this image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtLdy.png

I am stuck here .It will be really helpful if i get some help .
Thank you.

Comment: lambda isn't logging _anything_? Fix that. We don't have enough information to have any chance of helping you here.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I have uploaded a picture of log . Actually it shows executed successfully . There is no error . I have tested it in api gateway .

Comment: Please provide textual content as text, not images. Screenshots can't be searched, or copied and pasted; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122

Comment: If you're going to do a single row insert followed by a commit, then you can save time and just use autocommit instead of an explicit commit - check the cx_Oracle manual.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're getting an error other than an IntegrityError and don't have an explicit error handler for it. This would cause you to continue towards your *this is fine* return method.

In fact, updating a password shouldn't throw an integrity error at all since you're not operating on something that effects your schema or is effected by a schema constraint. According to the docs:

> This exception is raised when the relational integrity of the data is affected. For example, a duplicate key was inserted or a foreign key constraint would fail.

To troubleshoot, I'd start by accepting *any* error here. Once you've determined what error type you've caught, you can add per exception error handling as needed.

```python
except Exception as e:
  errorObj, = e.args
  return {
    ...
```

Comment: @Jcobm001 Thanks a lot answering . But no luck . There is no exception . I dont know whats happening . I have tested this query in sqldeveloper . Its woked . But when i try this using aws lambda it does not show any error . Also it does not update the value .